# Как мне разместить Label по середине окна?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label

Как мне разместить лейбл по середине окна (в независимости от его размера) и каким менеджером по разметку пользоваться для этого?

```
from tkinter import *


#win
root=Tk()
root.title('-')
root.geometry('400x400')
root.resizable(False,False)
root.config(bg='brown')

#icon
photo = PhotoImage(file='icone.png')
root.iconphoto(False,photo)

lbltime=Label(root,text='0',padx=50)

# lbltime.???

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант:

```
from tkinter import *


root=Tk()
root.title('Title')
root.geometry('400x400')
#root.resizable(False, False)
root.config(bg='brown')

photo = PhotoImage(file='Ok.png')
root.iconphoto(False, photo)

lbltime=Label(root,text='Hello World')
lbltime.pack(fill='both', expand=True)                                       # !!! +++

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Наипростейший способ это использовать атрибут `expand` метода `pack`, то есть в вашем случае получается

```
lbltime=Label(root,text='0',padx=50)
lbltime.pack(expand = True)
```

Также можно использовать `relx` и `rely` метода `place`, они закрепляют объект в позиции от 0 до 1(где "1" это крайняя точка, а "0" начальная), например `relx=0, rely=0` будет означать что объект будет расположен на левом верхнем углу и позиция не будет изменяться в зависимости от размера окна.